# Asynchronous request to a process with python

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have a question about asynchronous call to a running process.
For example, I have a program written in python. (call it test.py)

```
import time

def run():
   while True:
       print "This is run function print"
       time.spleep(2)

def get_dict()
   return {'a': 1}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Now, I run test.py, and after that I want asynchronously make a web request to that process and get the value of a get_dict function.
Is it possible?

I ave tried to use tornado IOLoop, to make a web request to the test.py

I am absolute zero in async programming, and really have no a clear idea, how it should be done. Because of that, my question can be very confusing.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be asynchronously *making* the request, but asynchronously *responding* to it. But you'll need to post more details about what both the server and the client are actually doing.

Comment: sorry I did not add a wile loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Tornado and run this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from tornado import gen, ioloop, web

i = 0

@gen.coroutine
def run():
    global i
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    while True:
        print "This is run function print"
        yield gen.Task(loop.add_timeout, timedelta(seconds=1))
        i += 1


def get_dict():
    return {'a': i}


class DictHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Tornado converts dicts to JSON.
        self.finish(get_dict())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = web.Application([
        ('/dict', DictHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    print 'Listening on http://localhost:8888'
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(run)
```

`IOLoop.run_sync` runs until your `run` method quits. Visit `http://localhost:8888` to see the current value of `i`. Hit Ctrl-C in the terminal to end the program.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was needed to read SO docs, and I forgot to mark it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your Python application to include a server that responds to external requests and can execute functions on behalf of these external requests. Some ways of doing this include embedding a full-fledged HTTP server in your Python application to expose this kind of functionality or embedding a lighter-weight RPC server. Since it sounds like you want to expose this functionality to another application, an RPC approach is probably the more sensible one.

Personally, I would recommend using a combination of [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and [protobuf-socket-rpc](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-socket-rpc/). The protocol buffers library makes it easy to declare the data and RPC service functionality in an interface definition language (protocol buffers) and generate code in Python, C++, Java, and other languages that can read/write data in this format. The protocol buffer code also generates a generic service stub that you can use to provide an implementation of  a service. The protobuf-socket-rpc library allows you to easily create a server that exports your service implementation as well as to create a remote/rpc client that executes by making a connection to the application that provides the service implementation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am going to use Tornado Http server to achieve this aim, but still cannot understand, how to use it.